# Laravel store image into public/images

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, routes, public

I use Laravel 5.1 framework and I need to store images, so I decide to be `/public/images` folder with 777 permision.

So at table `article` at column `photo` I store url:

> http://domain.com/public/images/odOlG.jpg

Now when I try to get it - when I try url: http://domain.com/public/images/odOlG.jpg

I get this error from Laravel:
[image]

So how to solve this problem? Why Laravel need route for file - image...
also yes I check and image is into `/public/images` folder...

Comment: What web server do you use - Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Apache..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use URL without `public`:

```
http://domain.com/images/odOlG.jpg
```

If it doesn't work, but I have `odOlG.jpg` in `/public/images directory`, then your web server configuration is wrong. You should point Apache to a `public` folder, not the Laravel's root project, like this:

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel_project/public">
```

Comment: Glad it was helpful.